# Looking for a program that plays a sound on key press

Tags: python

I am physically disabled and need a program that makes my keys make a *thunk* noise (like a typewriter would). In 2011, someone wrote a Python 2 program but it doesn't work on 16.04 anymore.

I just installed `python-gtk2` which was missing.  Rebooted, (etc); the program cannot find gst to import.

**Update:** I've found a program in the meantime. It is helpful, but nowhere near as good as the solid *thunk* the Python program gave me.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://stackoverflow.com/  You probably need to update the script to work with Gst 1.x and the old script is assuming Gst 0.x) and that requires a coder. Plus you might need to "import" modules into your python.

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years old, but sounds like what you are looking for:

https://github.com/colszowka/linux-typewriter

And, just FYI, there is a long standing unresolved bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/conspy/+bug/1071836) in conspy addressing the fact that "xset c" doesn't do what it is supposed to. Maybe if enough people nominate it, we can get it addressed.